# Calling send() closes the applicaiton without error

Tags: c++, posix, centos7

I have a client application sending data over tcp. At some point, a call to send() returns without having sent all the available bytes and the next call to send closes the application without any kind of error.

The loop that calls send() looks like this:

```
  // m_buf is an std::vector of size 65536
  auto total_bytes = fill_buffer(m_buf.data(),m_buf.size());
  while(total_bytes > 0){
    // m_socket is a straightforward wrapper around a socket descriptor that
    // throws if a call to send() returns an error.
    auto total_bytes_sent = m_socket.send(m_buf.data(),total_bytes);
    auto remaining_bytes  = total_bytes - total_bytes_sent;
    while(remaining_bytes > 0){
      total_bytes_sent += m_socket.send(m_buf.data()+total_bytes_sent,remaining_bytes);
      remaining_bytes   = total_bytes - total_bytes_sent;
    }
    total_bytes = fill_buffer(m_buf.data(),m_buf.size());
  }
```

I also got some debug print:

```
send: total_bytes 65536
send: total_bytes_sent 65536
send: remaining_bytes 0
send: total_bytes 65536
send: total_bytes_sent 65536
send: remaining_bytes 0
send: total_bytes 65536
send: total_bytes_sent 65536
send: remaining_bytes 0
send: total_bytes 65536
send: total_bytes_sent 65536
send: remaining_bytes 0
send: total_bytes 65536
send: total_bytes_sent 65536
send: remaining_bytes 0
send: total_bytes 65536
send: total_bytes_sent 65536
send: remaining_bytes 0
send: total_bytes 65536
send: total_bytes_sent 65536
send: remaining_bytes 0
send: total_bytes 65536
send: total_bytes_sent 8127
send: remaining_bytes 57409
[computer@localhost test]$
```

At the end, send() was called to send the remaining_bytes but the call never returns (no exceptions have been catched either) and the application closes.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The output you posted is not from the code you show

Comment: "throws if a call to send() returns an error." if you dont catch the exception your program will terminate, afaik a message appearing in that case is just the compiler being nice to you but not mandatory

Comment: The original source code contains many files and providing a complete and minimal example is somewhat incompatible. Exceptions are properly handled but i can't include all the source code that lead to the exception handler.

Comment: in mcve "complete" means "enough code to reproduce the problem" not "complete" as in "post all your code". At the very least you could post code that matches the output, not code and output that are unrelated

Comment: btw creating a mcve is a extremely useful tool for debugging. If it is impossible for you to isolate the problem and generate a mcve then you have a more general problem

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is you are getting an error return from send() but you aren't checking for -1.  That could make total_bytes_sent a negative number, which would put your second send into invalid memory.

Comment: An exception is raised by the m_socket.send() method if the underlying call to posix send() returns -1. Those exceptions are catched in a handler located in the top level method that leads to m_socket.send().